# Stuck with Api response Ktor

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I am trying to build a KMM application using Ktor for our ApiServices. I have created a `BaseApiClass` where I have all of the api related code.

Code for `BaseApiClass` :-

```
class BaseAPIClass {

//Create Http Client
private val httpClient by lazy {
    HttpClient {
        defaultRequest {
            host = ApiEndPoints.Base.url
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            header(CONNECTION, CLOSE)
        }
        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.DEFAULT
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
        install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = NETWORK_REQUEST_TIMEOUT
        }
        expectSuccess = false
        // JSON Deserializer
        install(JsonFeature) {
            val json = Json {
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                coerceInputValues = true
            }
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
        }
    }
}


// Api Calling Functions I have few more similar to this but issue is random and comes in any of the api
@Throws(Exception::class)
suspend fun sampleApi(requestBody: RequestBody?) : Either<CustomException, BaseResponse<EmptyResponseModel>> {
    return try {
        val response = httpClient.post<BaseResponse<EmptyResponseModel>> {
            url(ApiEndPoints.sample.url)
            if (requestBody != null) {
                body = requestBody
            }
        }
        Success(response)
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        Failure(e as CustomException)
    }
}
```

Here's how I call the api from iOS app :-

```
val apiClass = BaseApiClass()

func callApi() {
        apiClass.sampleApi(requestBody: .init(string: "value here")) { (result, error) in
            result?.fold(failed: { (error) -> Any? in
                // Error here 
            }, succeeded: { (result) -> Any? in
                // Success here 
            })
        }
    }
```

Now here if I try to call similar few more api's with the same `object` i.e `apiClass` then after few calls it get stuck inside my function `callApi` it don't send even api request (Because I can't see Request Logs printed in my console) and because of that I cannot do any other operations as I don't get anything from api.

As soon as I change my screen or close the app and try to call the same api then it works good.

But instead of creating a object only at one time like this `apiClass = BaseApiClass()` if I try  to do with `BaseApiClass().sampleApi(request params here) {// completion handler here}` it works fine I don't get any issues with this.

I am not sure what causes this to happen everything works good in `Android` this is faced only with `iOS`.

Comment: This seems like a bug, probably worth filing an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KTOR. Also, consider attaching a project to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the efforts and trying a lot of debugging skills I got to understand that my completion handler in the shared module is never called even if I receive the response the response from api.

The only solution I have achieved is creating the different HTTP Client using `expect` and `actual` mechanism. By making separate clients I have not encountered the issue yet.

If you have any other answers or solutions I would be happy to have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set **LogLevel.NONE** in the **install(Logging) block**.
At the moment I resolved in this way because it seems a bug of Ktor.
See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-2711
It should be fixed in the version **1.6.0**.

Comment: Looks like the issue is still there in 1.6.7. Anyway, this solved a similar issue for me.

Comment: Yes indeed, the Ktor team said to me that this stuck issue will be solved only in the version 2.0.0 that should be released very soon. No fix in the patch releases.
See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-2986

Comment: Thanks for the link! Fingers crossed that we can enable logging again with 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the multithreaded variant of the Coroutines library? The official docs state that you should use this variant when working with Ktor. See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines)